# Reversing shortest paths among unit disks

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, plane-geometry

```
Twas the night before Christmas, and throughout M.O.
Not a question was posted, not even by Joe.
```

Well, let me remedy that. :-)

Let the plane contain a number of pairwise disjoint open unit-radius disk
obstacles.
Because they are open, their bounding circles can touch tangentially.
Shortest paths between
two points $a$ and $b$ in the complement
of the disks generally look like this:

   [image: UnitDiskPath2]
Notice that the (red) path from $a$ to $b$ is *monotonic*
with respect to the line containing
$a$ and $b$—it meets every line orthogonal
to $ab$ in a single point—and in that sense never "reverses direction."
However, it *is* possible for a shortest path to reverse direction, e.g.:

   [image: UnitDiskPath1]
Here the red path, which reverses direction slightly near $b$,
is a bit shorter than the blue path:
$$
\pi + 2 + \epsilon < \frac{5}{3}\pi - \epsilon
$$
$$
5.14 + \epsilon < 5.24 - \epsilon
$$
for sufficiently small $\epsilon$, e.g., $\epsilon = 5^\circ$.

However, I am hoping this has a positive answer:

> **Q1**. If the disks form an infinite hexagonal penny packing,
>   are all shortest paths
>   (between pairs of points in the complement of the packing)
>   monotonic with respect the line through the endpoints?

More generally:

> **Q2**. If the disk centers form a regular lattice of $\mathbb{R}^2$,
>   are all shortest paths monotonic?

Here I am not requiring that the disk boundaries be tangent, but
rather just that the disks form a regular array. I am wondering if it is
irregularity that allows nonmontonic geodesics.

The context is that, perhaps, in disk arrangments where the shortest paths are 
monotonic, the $O(n^2)$ algorithms for finding
a shortest path amidst $n$ disks can be improved to subquadratic.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but isn't your second example already a counterexample to Q1?

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez, I think that Q1 refers to the packing of the entire plane, not just a little piece of it.

Comment: @RodrigoA.Pérez: Gerry is correct. Apologies for the lack of clarity. Repaired now.

Comment: Consider a proof by induction.  Given a point a, show that all points in a ball centered at a with a radius of r+epsilon have such a monotonic path given all point in an r-ball have such paths.

Comment: @TheMaskedAvenger: In my 3-disk example, I believe all shortest paths within $r=\pi+2$ are monotonic, but at $r+\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$, there are nonmonotonic shortest paths.

Comment: Yes, and that field of disks lacks sufficient symmetry (and also has a counterexample) for an induction proof to work.  I suggest a proof by induction as one way to capitalize on the regularity of the space.  To make it more real, here is a suggestion: Look at the circles intersecting the line between a and b; there is a shortest path involving only those circles and some of their neighbors.